# Attribute information not matching up when searching by a custom field (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have extended my search to include custom fields (brand, colour), its returning all the results I expect.. but when using the Layered Nav widget to filter by attributes the count is not matching up. I know the product returned has the correct attributes, for example - size:

```
            <div class="sizeavailable">

               <?php
                    $sizevalues = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_size');

                  foreach ( $sizevalues as $sizevalue ) {
                   echo  $sizevalue->name."&nbsp;";
                    }
                ?>

            </div>
```

And im seeing size 10, 12, 14 and so on, but the number count on the Layered nav is not reflecting this. The layered nav is only display attribute data for a product with the custom field term in the product title.

So in my test data, I have 200 products in size 10, but after the search the layered nav list is showing only a number of 5, but upon clicking on the size 10 filter 200 products are returned.

Below are function/s that join the post metadata to the search:

```
// hook into wp pre_get_posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'jc_woo_search_pre_get_posts');

/**
 * Add custom join and where statements to product search query
 * @param  mixed $q query object
* @return void
*/
function jc_woo_search_pre_get_posts($q){

if ( is_search() ) {
    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'jc_search_post_join' );
    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'jc_search_post_excerpt' );
}
}

/**
 * Add Custom Join Code for wp_mostmeta table
 * @param  string $join
 * @return string
 */
function jc_search_post_join($join = ''){

global $wp_the_query;

// escape if not woocommerce searcg query
if ( empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) || empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
        return $join;

$join .= "INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS jcmt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = jcmt1.post_id)";
return $join;
}

/**
 * Add custom where statement to product search query
 * @param  string $where
 * @return string
 */
function jc_search_post_excerpt($where = ''){

global $product;
global $wp_the_query;

// escape if not woocommerce search query
if ( empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) || empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
        return $where;

$where = preg_replace("/post_title LIKE ('%[^%]+%')/", "post_title LIKE $1)
            OR (jcmt1.meta_key = 'brand' AND CAST(jcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1)
            OR  (jcmt1.meta_key = 'colour' AND CAST(jcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1", $where);

return $where;
}
```

Comment: http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/ :this example you are posting here.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/ use this plugin.

Comment: Yeah thats the example, will this sync the attribute numbers in the layered nav?

Comment: why don't use plugin

Comment: That plugin looks overkill for what im doing.